# How to json marshal without omitempty on struct fields

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I have a **generated type** `A`,

I want to `json.Marshal` the type and to ignore any empty fields while testing.

The generated type comes without `json:",omitempty"` for any struct fields, nor would I want to for purposes of the application itself.

What would be the best way to marshal my type without providing empty fields?

Cheers!

Comment: Why do you want to marshal it without empty fields? For testing, you can create a new type B with omitempty types, copy A into B and marshal that. Another option: marshal A, unmarshal to map[string]any, write an algorithm to remove all empty fields, and marshal that.

Comment: @BurakSerdar, I want to marshal without empty fields as means of reducing additional text when I go to test.  Expected output for tests are represented as json encoding. Showing which values are non-nil / non-zero makes it easier to review output.

Comment: Ideally I don't want to have copy types between A into B. My types are dynamically generated and I'd like to avoid such maintenance if at all possible. I'm open to what options there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simples way is crate new type for testing with the same field as `A` and use one in tests:

```golang
type A struct {
    Val  string `json:"val"`
    Val2 int    `json:"val2"`
}
```

```
type testA struct {
    Val  string `json:"val,omitempty"`
    Val2 int    `json:"val2,omitempty"`
}

func Test(t *testing.T) {
    a := A{
        Val:  "some",
        Val2: 0,
    }

    t.Run("cast", func(t *testing.T) {
        ab, _ := json.Marshal(a)
        t.Log(string(ab))
        ab, _ = json.Marshal(testA(a))
        t.Log(string(ab))
    })
}
```

```
=== RUN   Test
=== RUN   Test/cust
    some_test.go:26: {"val":"some","val2":0}
    some_test.go:28: {"val":"some"}
--- PASS: Test (0.00s)
    --- PASS: Test/cust (0.00s)
```

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://go.dev/play/p/jlgj-8K1t7t)</kbd>

Other way is creating new type base on `A`, implements [Marshaler](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshaler) for new type and create struct with the same fields and tags (with `omitempty`) dynamically use [reflect](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect) package:

```
type testAV2 A

func (u testAV2) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    value := reflect.ValueOf(u)
    t := value.Type()
    sf := make([]reflect.StructField, 0)
    // modify the 'fori' snippet for more complicated cases 
    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        sf = append(sf, t.Field(i))
        tag := t.Field(i).Tag
        if !strings.Contains(string(tag), ",omitempty") {
            r := regexp.MustCompile(`json:"\s*(.*?)\s*"`)
            matches := r.FindAllStringSubmatch(string(tag), -1)
            for _, v := range matches {
                tagKey := v[1]
                sf[i].Tag = reflect.StructTag(fmt.Sprintf(`json:"%s,omitempty"`, tagKey))
            }
        }
    }
    newType := reflect.StructOf(sf)
    newValue := value.Convert(newType)
    return json.Marshal(newValue.Interface())
}
```

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://go.dev/play/p/y15UvEJL38-)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks @kozmo, ideally I wouldn't have to copy values as this adds concern for maintenance as type A is subject to change over time. It's always good to see a dumb version approach though. Cheers :)

Comment: Appreciate the update @kozmo. Chur bro!